# Approach to get rid of controller GET-actions that just return view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Most of actions in controllers of a project simply return corresponding view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

I wonder is there any approach to get rid of such GET-actions and map url directly to view?
For example: '/home/index' renders view '~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml'

**Sample code of solution** suggested by Chaim Brykman (@haim770): https://github.com/artplastika/ViewWithoutControllerDemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `ViewRenderer` action in some Controller:

```
public ViewResult ViewRenderer(string viewPath)
{
    var extractedPath = viewPath.Split('/');

    this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = extractedPath[0];
    this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = extractedPath[1];

    return View();
}
```

Then, in your `RoutesConfig`, add the following route before the default (last) route, changing the Controller name appropriately:

```
// Views Renderer
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ViewsRenderer",
    url: "Static/{*viewPath}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Common", action = "ViewRenderer" }
);
```

The URL would be:

```
http://your_host_name/Static/Home/Index
```

(You can change 'Static' to whatever you like)

This is a very basic implementation and it does not take Areas into account (can be easily adjusted though). It also doesn't handle all the security implications that this change may introduce (depending on the nature of your application).

Comment: This will give 404 without having in code actual controller class with specified action.

Comment: Does it at least hit the `ViewRenderer` action?

Comment: It's not going to work this way. You need to register the route exactly as specified: `url: "Static/{*viewPath}"` then call it with `Static` prefix as well.

Comment: Then your answer is not a solution for my task, because I need *exactly the same* url routing as it would be with controllers presence.

Comment: Seems to be my mistake: url: "{*viewPath}" works as expected. Hm. I will check everything once more and then accept the answer)